# Accessing the properties in scheama methods via " this "

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Hey guys i was just trying to make use of mongoose schema methods in Nodejs project so faced a problem here

In my controller file i extracted the id of my Comment in db and then
called a method in Comments modal file like

```
exports.getupvote=(req,res,next)=>{

  const id=req.params.id
  console.log(id)
  Comments.findById(id).then(c=>{
    console.log(c)
    Comments.upvoteco(c)
  })
  res.redirect('/')
}
```

and then in my comments modal file i have

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const commentsschema = new Schema({
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  middlename:{
    type:String
  },
  lastname:{
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  comments:{
      type:String,
      required:true
  },
  upvote:{
      type:Number
  },
  downvote:{
      type:Number
  }

});
commentsschema.statics.upvoteco=function(c){

  console.log(c.upvote)
  console.log(this.firstname)
}

module.exports = mongoose.model("comments", commentsschema);
```

now console.log(this.firstname) gives me undefined ..why ? even though i have entries in my db as

https://ibb.co/p0SdzYW

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like that:

```
const parent = commentsschema;
commentsschema.statics.upvoteco=function(c){

  console.log(c.upvote)
  console.log(parent.firstname)
}

module.exports = mongoose.model("comments", commentsschema);
```

If you try to use `this` in the function you are referring to the function iteslf

Comment: still gives undefined :(

Comment: any other way we could achieve this ?

Comment: Not sure it it can help but take a look here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#methods